# How to reliably obtain "On resume, display logon screen" for a Windows screensaver?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screensaver, windows-screensaver

Am I missing something? I run the following code on my Vista laptop from a user-mode process:

```
BOOL bSecure = -100;
if(::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVESECURE, NULL, &bSecure, 0))
{
    int success = 1;
}
```

The purpose is to obtain the "On resume, display logon screen" screensaver setting (circled in red below):

[image]

`SystemParametersInfo` succeeds but `bSecure` is not changed.

For those who may not believe me, here's the screenshot from the VS debugger:

[image]

Upon further debugging it turns out that `SystemParametersInfo` actually returns `0xC0000002` when on my other computer it returns `1` when it succeeds. I thought it is not supposed to return HRESULT, or is it?

Anyway, the question -- how to reliably obtain this setting?

Comment: *If the function succeeds, the return value is a nonzero value.* - Nothing to do with `HRESULT`. You can't make the assumption it is one. FWIW, works fine on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @chris: I know. It worked on 99% of other OS I tried this code on.